# How to pass data to resource from admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a prop on app.js. I want to pass this prop to another child page.

This is app.js:

```
<Admin
   <Resource name="Stores" options={{ label: 'Stores' }}  list={Store} storeId={this.props.storeId}/>
Admin>
```

And this is Store.js:

```
export const Store = (storeId) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Here
      {storeId}
    </div>
  )
}
```

app.js has the `storeId` variable. I can see it from reactjs components tool on chrome. But `storeId` doesn't seem to be on Store.js page.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can be passed via 'options':

```
app.js:

<Admin
   <Resource name="Stores" options={{ label: 'Stores', storeId: props.storeId }} list={Store} />
Admin>

Store.js:

export const Store = ({ options, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Here
      {options.storeId}
    </div>
  )
}
```